# God messing with Date Operations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, god

This is a weired think. Follow my steps:

Without god, on console:

```
> d=Date.parse("2010-02-01")
=> Mon, 01 Feb 2010
> d+1.day
=> Tue, 02 Feb 2010
```

Perfect.

Then, I go to my Gemfile and add

```
gem 'god'
```

and run

```
bundle install
```

After that, on console again:

```
> d=Date.parse("2010-02-01")
=> Mon, 01 Feb 2010 
> d+1.day
=> Sun, 23 Aug 2246
```

Do you know what could be happening?

Comment: Gotta hate those divine acts of intervention eh?

Comment: Clearly, it is a divine intervention ;-)

Comment: Become an atheist, then you won't need to bother with God :P

Comment: You are funny, but seriously, I'm starting to doubt of God's power :P

Comment: I would have doubts about any gem named god.  If this is specific to time manipulations, it should be called timelord.

Comment: It is not. It is a process monitoring, so He decides who lives and who dies :O

Comment: @DonRoby we don't have a timelord gem, but there is a very popular gem for time manipulation in tests called timecop

Comment: Actually I think that gem should be called `Einstein`.

Comment: You're a fundamentalist, assuming that a day is a literal day. Obviously, a day can be any period of time.

Answer (score 2):

Odd that this is happening in a console.  I could have understood it in other scenarios, where 1.day is being used as an input in one place and extracted for use somewhere else, since 1.day is the Fixnum 86400, with some special metadata (`#steps`) mixed into it.

`Date` treats, for example, `+ 1` to mean "add one day".  Rails adds some behaviour so that it understands the `1.day` thing (86400 "seconds", but with a `step` of `[1, :days]`) to actually mean `+ 1` instead of `+ 86400`.  This is what you're losing:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :171 > d = Date.parse("2010-02-01")
 => #<Date: 2010-02-01 (4910457/2,0,2299161)> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :172 > d + 86400
 => #<Date: 2246-08-23 (5083257/2,0,2299161)> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :173 >
```

So the value `1.day` is being interpreted as a Fixnum, rather than a Fixnum with `ActiveSupport::Duration`.

```
irb(main):001:0> Date.parse("2010-02-01") + 1.day.to_i
=> Sun, 23 Aug 2246
```

So if you're using this `1.day` value in a context where it is not being immediately consumed, don't... use the Fixnum 1 instead ;)

Answer (score 1):

"god" makes a mess of Dates. This is a problem with "god". A gem used with Rails should not alter Rails conventions. If Date.current - 4.days does one thing without "god", then it should do that with "god". Period.

Comment: Interesting. Can you give a link to more info about this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [GitHub open issue](https://github.com/mojombo/god/issues/17), i tried this solution :

Gemfile

```
gem 'god', :require => false
```

Instead of :

```
gem 'god'
```

The everything seem to work again :

```
1.9.3p0 :001 > d = Date.parse('2012-04-16')
 => Mon, 16 Apr 2012 
1.9.3p0 :002 > d + 1.day
 => Tue, 17 Apr 2012
```